# is there a way to group desktop icons on the task bar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

i have a folder on the desktop which has a bunch of programs i use frequently, i can't pin all these programs to the taskbar themselves as there are too many for the screen width that it'll just make the taskbar scrollable

i am wondering if i can do one of the following

1. pin the icons to the taskbar under 1 icon
2. pin the folder to the taskbar separately to the Windows Explorer button which when there are no folders open will open up the libraries and if there are folders it'll show me the folders open, this way if i have 5 folders open and my frequently used programs folder i can just click on the frequently used programs folder icon on the taskbar and be given that folder only

i'm trying to reduce the number of clicks, scrolling or scanning across the task bar i need to do in order to find a program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add these as a new toolbar on the taskbar.  Put all the shortcuts into a folder, then right click the taskbar and select `Toolbar / New Toolbar...`

Navigate to the folder with the shortcuts and select it.  It will look like this:

[image]

So that is 1 click to expand, and 1 click to open the app.

Comment: Yep, that's good, there's no way i can use an icon instead of text is there? just curious

Comment: @Memor-X I don't think so, but you could change the name of the folder to something short, like `'` or `º` to make it less obtrusive.

Answer (score 1):

The way you've described it won't work -- you can pin the folder to the Windows Explorer icon on the taskbar, but when you click it, it will simply open up the folder with your icons.

Number of clicks for this scenario: 3 (or 4 if you're double clicking to open the application).

Have you thought about adjusting the taskbar icons to be a smaller size? Then you can pin more: [image]